# How to combine multiple rows of varying amounts of data into one row in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, inner-join

I've seen the multiple entries similar to this one but can't find one that fits my specific needs so sorry if this is considered a repost.

Note; Using Sql Server 2012 and am just past beginner in level of knowledge of programming, so might still be missing something obvious.

I have a table called Results that outputs the following (With example data)

```
------------------------------------------------------------
UID | LotNum | SerNum | ResultValue| ResultCode | TestType |
------------------------------------------------------------
1   | Lot1   | 1234   | 10         |    1       | 1        |
------------------------------------------------------------
2   | Lot1  | 1234   | 5          |    1       | 1        |
------------------------------------------------------------
3   | Lot1  | 1234   | 2          |    2       | 1        |
------------------------------------------------------------
4   | Lot1  | 2345   | 5          |    1       | 1        |
------------------------------------------------------------
5   | Lot1  | 2345   | 2          |    2       | 1        |
------------------------------------------------------------
6   | Lot1  | 2345   | 2          |    2       | 1        |
```

The UID is autogenerated, the rest is entered and the maximum amount of tests per serial number is 3.

I'm trying to pull some of this data into a single row based off of the Serial Number so I can easily combine it with a separate table using a stored procedure. 
This new table looks like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
SerNum | UID1 | Result1 | UID2 | Result2 | UID3 | Result 3
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Where the UIDs and Results can be null, and SerNum is not necessarily sequential (as shown in the example data).

I've tried several things but the closest I have gotten is

```
Alter Procedure [dbo].[spSerialNum](
                @LotNum varchar(50)
      )
AS

Truncate Table dbo.tbl_Serial_Num

Begin

  Insert into dbo.tbl_Serial_Num (Serial_Num, UID1, Result1, UID2, Result2, UID3, Result 3)
  Select A.SerNum, A.UID, A.ResultCode, B.UID, B.ResultCode, C.UID, C.ResultCode
  From dbo.tbl_Results A
  Left Join dbo.tbl_Results B ON A.LotNum = B.LotNum and A.SerNum = B.SerNum and A.UID < B.UID
  Left Join dbo.tbl_Results C ON A.LotNum = C.LotNum and A.SerNum = C.SerNum and B.UID < C.UID
  Where A.LotNum = @LotNum
```

This however returns a table that looks like this
[image]

How do I get rid of the duplicate rows (If I am understanding it correctly its executing for every row of original data); is the Left Self Join not the right option for this or am I just missing a predicate?

Comment: You are wanting a pivot here...

Comment: I had looked at that but wasn't sure that applied since I am not using an aggregate

Comment: so UID is pointless, right? You just want the UID to be 1-3 or you want a UID for each UID...?

Comment: the UID1-UID3 is the UIDs grabbed from the rows of the test results and are created in the other table, was asked to bring them into the new table for cross reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way that doesn't use pivot since you stated they can only have 3 instances...

```
create table #tempTable([UID] int,LotNum varchar(16),SerNum int, ResultValue int, ResultCode int , TestType int)
insert into #tempTable
values
(1,'Lot1',1234,10,1,1),
(2,'Lot1',1234,5,1,1),
(3,'Lot1',1234,2,2,1),
(4,'Lot1',2345,5,1,1),
(5,'Lot1',2345,2,2,1),
(6,'Lot1',2345,2,2,1)

;with cte as(
select
    row_number() over (partition by SerNum order by [UID]) as RN
    ,[UID]
    --,LotNum
    ,SerNum
    --,ResultValue
    ,ResultCode
    --,TestType
from 
    #tempTable)

select
    s1.SerNum
    ,s1.UID as UID1
    ,s1.ResultCode as Result1
    ,s2.UID as UID2
    ,s2.ResultCode as Result2
    ,s3.UID as UID3
    ,s3.ResultCode as Result3
from
    cte s1
    left join
        cte s2 on s2.SerNum = s1.SerNum and s2.RN = s1.RN + 1
    left join
        cte s3 on s3.SerNum = s1.SerNum and s3.RN = s1.RN + 2
where
    s1.RN = 1


drop table #tempTable
```

**RETURNS**

```
+--------+------+---------+------+---------+------+---------+
| SerNum | UID1 | Result1 | UID2 | Result2 | UID3 | Result3 |
+--------+------+---------+------+---------+------+---------+
|   1234 |    1 |       1 |    2 |       1 |    3 |       2 |
|   2345 |    4 |       1 |    5 |       2 |    6 |       2 |
+--------+------+---------+------+---------+------+---------+
```

Comment: (This being I am new to also using stackoverflow) So where you have the values I should have my select from the original table I am pulling from correct? and with the #tempTable should that be the table I am currently have been using or another one added on?

Comment: The temp table is simply your table. In this example scsimon created a temp table to make his solution runnable/testable and thus easier to understand.

Comment: What @Karel-JanMisseghers said is correct. Remove everything before `;with` and replace #tempTable with what ever your table name is and it will work. Also don't forget to remove `drop table #tempTable`

Comment: I wasn't able to test it yesterday and my supervisor recommended a different way to do it that I am currently testing and getting closer results . Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult one, as you cannot guarantuee that there will only be 3 results in the dataset per serialNumber, and you cannot identify which is result1, which is result2 and which is result3.

Ideally, you would have an extra column to identify the result number within the SerialNumber set.

If you assume that there are no gaps in the UID's, you can take take the MIN(UID) per SerialNum as result1, MIN(UID)+1 as result2, MIN(UID)+2 as result3.
That way you can join on these 'modified' UID's, and filter on the MIN(UID), thus excluding the result2 and result3, to only get 1 row.

Edit; including a query I wrote, was not able to test it out though;

```
WITH serial_nums (serial_num, uid1) AS
(SELECT serial_num,
        min(UID) uid1
   FROM tbl_Serial_Num
  GROUP BY serial_num)
 SELECT res1.serial_num,
        res1.UID, res1.ResultCode, 
        res2.UID, res2.ResultCode,
        res3.UID, res3.ResultCode
   FROM serial_nums CTE
   JOIN tbl_Serial_Num res1
     ON res1.UID = CTE.uid1
   JOIN tbl_Serial_Num res2
     ON res2.UID = CTE.uid1+1
    AND res2.serial_num = res1.serial_num
   JOIN tbl_Serial_Num res3
     ON res3.UID = CTE.uid1+2
    AND res3.serial_num = res1.serial_num;
```

EDIT; fixed some more syntax issues regarding the common table expression

Comment: What does CTE stand for?

Comment: CTE is a common table expression. it is the 'serial_nums' I am creating on top of the select. More info here; https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/

Comment: I've made some syntax changes, as the previous query had some errors so defnitely wouldn't work (';'in the middle of the query etc.).

Comment: Was double checking data and due to data coming in from different stations its not guaranteed that one serial number will have sequential UIDs (ex; Ser1 Test1 has UID of 256 but the second set of data for Ser1 might not come in until UID 260).

Comment: Thinking about it for your method I could create another table to order them by SerialNumber and assign TempUIDs (while holding on to the originals) in order to get the correct sequencing....

Comment: OK, In that case, we can use 'RANK' in the CTE, to give the results a number. Let me take a look into that :)
EDIT; you've found the solution yourself at the same time apparently! No need to create another table, take a look here;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql
You can partition by over Serial_Num, and add a ROW_NUMBER, in the CTE.

Comment: Basically what 'scsimon's answer is doing.